# (JS) Скрипт для поиска по коду

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код
`<input id="radio-02" type="radio" name="radio-0" checkit="true">`
И если в нем `chekit=true`, то в класс нужно добавить значение `right-answer`
Как это сделать, учитывая, что у каждого `input` свои имя, класс, тип, но `true` стоит только у одного из них?

UPD: Я понял, что на сайте не важно, правильный ответ или нет. Если `checkit="true"`, то он посчитает это правдой, не важно так ли это.
Если написать скрипт, который меняет каждый `checkit` на странице на `checkit="true"`, то любой ответ будет верный.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value

Comment: ну вообще, наверное checked  = true

Comment: а зачем еще класс добавлять, если уже есть отличительный атрибут

Answer (score 0):

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[checked=true]");

elements.forEach((element) => {
    element.classList.add('right-answer')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = document.querySelectorAll('.input');

input.forEach(radio => radio.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
  Array.from(input).forEach(item => {
    item.classList.remove('right-answer')
  })
  event.target.classList.add('right-answer')
console.log(radio);
}));
```

```html
<input class="input" type="radio" name="radio">
 <input class="input" type="radio" name="radio">
```